# Вывод многострочного текста

Tags: java, swing

Как быстро выводить многострочный текст?

Возможен ли такой подход:
1. поместить текст в JTextArea, где текст будет отформатирован на строки
2. получить массив строк из JTextArea и выводить по отдельности каждую строку

Вопрос как получить массив строк из JTextArea или есть ещё варианты?

Comment: Вы понимаете что результат зависит от шрифта в конкретном JTextArea? Вы вряд ли хотите чтобы это было так. Что за задачу вы решаете?

Answer (score 0):

У класса JTextArea есть метод getText(), который возвращает текст в виде строки с учетом ее форматирования. 
Следовательно, можно получить текст из объекта TextArea и преобразовать его к массиву с помощью split(), например, 'разбив' полученную строку по символу переноса строки.

```
String s = textArea.getText();
String[] split = s.split("\\n");
for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Индекс значения в массиве: " + i + " его значение: " + split[i]);
}
```

*Результат выполнения кода:*

[image: input]

*Вывод в консоль:*

[image: output]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я немного о другом.
Например, есть обычная длинная строка без переносов. Если её поместить в JTextArea меньшей ширины чем строка, то JTextArea отформатировав в своём поле отобразит эту строку в виде нескольких подстрок.

Вот вопрос - как вывести также как и JTextArea. 

Для увеличения производительности неплохо бы было иметь массив этих отформатированных подстрок и просто выводить их как g.drawString(..), не заморачиваясь с LineBreakMeasurer. Или же нужно копать код JTextArea где осуществляется вывод и делать что-то подобное